# How to extract only specific parts from an image?

Tags: java, android

[image]

Hello, I have a task to build an android app that extracts only specific parts of an image.Like, for example, extract only the part of the image that contains the phone number above and then use an OCR to extract the text in that part.

I have already implemented Google's Text Recognition API to extract text from an image and it works good, but I don't want to extract everything, just a specific part.

Is that possible? and if it is, what techniques should I use to solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: How do you want to chose which part of the image to extract?

Comment: that's what I'm trying to solve , i want the algorithm to know from where to extract in the image

Answer (score 1):

Without any context, I am not sure whether you can actually pinpoint where the phone number (in this example) is or not. So simple question would be no, in my humble opinion.

However, if you can change the problem domain a little bit, I think you can do what you are trying to do.

What I mean by that is simple. Before the image of that RX is taken, can you ask the person who is taking picture or who is scanning that document to **highlight** the phone number field? Or can you ask them to put the phone number in a box? (Or simply, make the phone number look different from the rest of the info). If they can do so, you can then spot the highlighted portion, (or look for the box, or whatever else they did to differentiate the phone number field) separate it from the rest of the image and send it over to google API.

I know this solution may require human intervention and prone to error, or require messing with the problem domain. However, it may solve the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

The only general technique would be to ask a real person to designate (i.e. using a mouse) the area to be extracted.  But this will fail when the person gets tired, bored, asks for a pay raise, etc.

If you know where the phone number will (always) be in the image (e.g. 50 pixels from the top) then you can find based on that.  But this will fail if the documents are not aligned when scanning, if they are laid out inconsistently and so on.

But, frankly, the most reliable and cheapest solution will be to OCR the entire image and identify the phone number based on the OCR'd characters.